# Why can't I compare an input to a random number in Python

Tags: python

So I basically wanna compare "Number" and "Guess" in the if statement, but no matter what it says they don't match (I get the else response, not included here). Even if I copy the random number they don't match. 
Thanks in advance!

```
import time
def the_start():
    points = 0
    attempt = 1
    print("Attempt:",attempt)
    print("Your goal is to guess a number between 1 and 10 - Points:",points)
    time.sleep(2)
    attempt = attempt + 1
    number = random.randint(0,10)
    print(number)
    guess = input("What is your guess?  :")
    time.sleep(2)

    if guess == number:
        points = points + 1
        print("OMG YOU WERE RIGHT! Here, have some fake cheers! *cheer*")
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: `guess` is a string, `number` is a number they can't be equal

Comment: Like should I do
number = 0
guess = 0
before the start?

Comment: @OliverFrost is the `if guess == number:` comparison inside or outside the  `def the_start():`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

guess is a string.  You need to do conversion of the string and handle error conditions.  int() will convert a string to an integer, but it will throw an exception if the string is not purely numbers.